# How to change the color of tabbed page indicator in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, indicator, tabbedpage

I'm making an app using Xamarin Forms. I have a tabbed page and wish to change the color of the tabbed indicator. However I am unable to change it from the default of white.

A white indicator example:

[image: A white indicator example]

I've tried changing the tabIndicatorColor in the Tabbar.xml file as shown below:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colourSelected"
app:tabGravity="fill"
app:tabMode="fixed" />
```

However this doesn't change it, no matter what color I use, the indicator will still be white. How do I go about fixing this?

Comment: try with a hex code directly something like this 
`app:tabIndicatorColor="#FF9F11"`

Comment: I tried that, still no change

Comment: No, I was using TabbedPage. Changing the android compile version form 10.0 to 9.0 seems to fix the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took me a while, but the problem seems to be a bug compiling with Android 10.0. Changing the "Compile using Android version" option to 9.0 from 10.0 in the android application screen fixed the problem.

After doing that, tabIndicatorColor works as intended.

Comment: seems like a bug you should raise it on github